# How to remove subdirectory using rewriterule with non-www redirection

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So I've been fiddling with .htaccess and I was able to remove both removing a subdirectory and having a non-www subdirection. Please find code below:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)subdir
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdir/$1 [L]
```

This can redirect:

> www.domain.com/subdir/file

or

> www.domain.com/file

to

> domain.com/file

However, it can't redirect

> domain.com/subdir/file

to

> domain.com/file

That's my only problem with this code. Could somebody enlighten me what am I doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `OR` condition in conditions:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /subdir/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:subdir/)?(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [NC,R=302,L]
```

Comment: Hi @anubhava , I tried and it led to an error of too many redirects

Comment: I have actually tested on my Apache. Do you have other rules also before this?

Comment: none. wait, should I replace the %1 in the last line to my domain?

Comment: Nope still not. Although I have rewriterules after this.

Comment: ok see updated rule. Make sure this is first rule in htaccess and you test in Chrome dev tool. You should post your current htaccess in question.